# React-native-router-flux - Lazy loading?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Which is the best way, to fetch initial data from a server for specific views after a user clicked on it?
I want to enable a user to have information directly as soon as he has a certain view which is defined with react-native-router-flux. Information should not be loaded when a user calls this view.
Is this possible and if so, how? Does anyone have an example for this ?